# How do I split this string using REGEX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
01/12/2015-04/27/2015 Lecture Monday, Wednesday, Friday 12:00PM - 12:50PM, CoolGuy Hall, Room 006 01/12/2015-04/27/2015 Laboratory Thursday 10:50AM - 12:05PM, Epic Science, Room 121
```

I am trying to parse it so I can get objects like so

```
{
 days: ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"]
 start: "12:00PM"
 end: "12:50PM"
 location: "CoolGuy Hall, Room 006"
}
```

and

```
{
 days: ["Thursday"]
 start: "10:50AM"
 end: "12:05PM"
 location: "Epic Science, Room 121"
}
```

Is there anyway to do this cleanly? I have tried using the split method using the dates:

```
/((..\/..\/....)-(..\/..\/....) \w+)/
```

to no avail and as you can see above my regex skills are fairly limited.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working for me... check is this you are trying to do...??

```
var data = "01/12/2015-04/27/2015 Lecture Monday, Wednesday, Friday 12:00PM - 12:50PM, CoolGuy Hall, Room 006 01/12/2015-04/27/2015 Laboratory Thursday 10:50AM - 12:05PM, Epic Science, Room 121"

data.replace(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\-\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} ([^\s]+) ([^\d]+) ([^\s]+) \- ([^,]+), ([^,]+), Room ([^\s]+)/g, "{\n\tdays: [$2]\n\tstart: \"$3\"\n\tend: \"$4\"\n\tlocation: \"$5, Room $6\"\n}\n");
```

Output:

```
{
    days: [Monday, Wednesday, Friday]
    start: "12:00PM"
    end: "12:50PM"
    location: "CoolGuy Hall, Room 006"
}
{
    days: [Thursday]
    start: "10:50AM"
    end: "12:05PM"
    location: "Epic Science, Room 121"
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have any further questions or face difficulties to understand any part of my code...

Comment: Holy f***, Thank you regex wizard! I wish I could give you more than one upvote